# How to prevent HTML file format changes when handling HTML file using cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

If I execute the following script, Line breaks are inserted in HTML or line breaks are deleted. 
Could you tell me how to handle it?

---

Improved Script
(This script preserves line breaks.)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const someFile = 'foo.html';
const beautify = require('js-beautify');
const beautifyOptions = {
  indent_size: 2,
  preserve_newlines: true,
  max_preserve_newlines: 0,
  extra_liners: [],
  indent_empty_lines: true
};

fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', (err,data) => {
  let $ = cheerio.load(data, { decodeEntities: false });
  let result = $.html();
    result = beautify.html(result, beautifyOptions);

  fs.writeFile(someFile, result, 'utf8', () => {});
});
```

Script

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const someFile = 'foo.html';

fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', (err,data) => {
  let $ = cheerio.load(data, { decodeEntities: false })
  const result = $.html();

  fs.writeFile(someFile, result, 'utf8', () => {});
});
```

HTML(Before)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="test">aaaaa</div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML(After)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="test">aaaaa</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: How is that "corrupted"? Looks fine to me. All it did was remove some whitespace, which doesn't matter for HTML at all. Unless you're getting some weird error, or the format of the source file is somehow important (you'll need to explain that), then don't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you for comment.Sorry for the confusing explanation.

Comment: cheerio looks like the wrong tool for your use case, you're not manipulating anything. and/or If you need a formatter, use something like [beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify#nodejs-javascript-1) before saving.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll give it a try.